# awk: test if the value in a column is less or more than others and make union

Tags: awk, compare, union

I am tring to use awk command to make union of these two data set. I would like to get all the lines in which fileA.$1 and fileB.$1 is same, and averagae of fileA.$4 and fileA.$5 is between fileB.$2 and fileB.$3. (fileA.$1=fileB.$1 AND fileB.$2 < average(fileA.$4+fileA.$5) < fileB.$3). Can anyone make a line for this?

```
fileA                           
chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    Mot TF  100 300 0.9893  target1 200
chr1    Mot TF  1000    2000    0.9893  target1 1500
chr2    Mot TF  500 700 0.9502  target2 600

fileB       
chr1    500 1000
chr1    400 800
chr1    100 800
chr3    100 500

desired result                              
chr1    500 1000    chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    400 800 chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    100 800 chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    100 800 chr1    Mot TF  100 300 0.9893  target1 200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = "\t"
}
NR == FNR {
    a0[NR] = $0
    a1[NR] = $1
    av[NR] = ($4 + $5) / 2
    next
}
{
    for (i = 1; i in a0; ++i) {
        if (a1[i] == $1 && av[i] > $2 && av[i] < $3) {
            print $0, a0[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Run with:

```
awk -f script.awk fileA fileB
```

Output:

```
chr1    500 1000    chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    400 800 chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    100 800 chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    100 800 chr1    Mot TF  100 300 0.9893  target1 200
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're flexible about the output format:

```
join fileB fileA | awk '$2 < $NF && $NF < $3'
```

```
chr1 500 1000 Mot TF 500 700 0.9893 target1 600
chr1 400 800 Mot TF 500 700 0.9893 target1 600
chr1 100 800 Mot TF 500 700 0.9893 target1 600
chr1 100 800 Mot TF 100 300 0.9893 target1 200
```

`join` does not print the join column twice. I assume that the last field of fileA is already the average.

Otherwise

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
    NR==FNR {f1[$0] = $1; min[$0] = $2; max[$0] = $3; next}
    {
        avg=($4+$5)/2
        for (b in f1) {
            if ($1 == f1[b] && min[b] < avg && avg < max[b]) {
                print b, $0
            }
        }
    }
' fileB fileA
```

```
chr1    100 800 chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    500 1000    chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    400 800 chr1    Mot TF  500 700 0.9893  target1 600
chr1    100 800 chr1    Mot TF  100 300 0.9893  target1 200
```

Comment: Thank you glenn, this is awesome !! Would you explain what exactly you did in      $2 < $NF && $NF < $3 ? How can we know which file the $2,$3 are assigned from? How   $NF && $NF can make average? @glenn jackman